# Import exact data from Excel to JS

Tags: javascript, excel

**UPD:** Question closed. I decided to use .csv instead of .xlsx and got a complete table from objects and arrays[image]

Updated code:

```js
const inputForm = document.getElementById("input-form")
const file = document.getElementById("file-choose")
const filterInput = document.getElementById("test-input")

let table = document.createElement("table")
let thead = document.createElement("thead")
let tbody = document.createElement("tbody")

function csvToArray(str, delimiter=',') {
   const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter)
   const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n")

   headers.pop()

   const arr = rows.map((row) => {
      const values = row.split(delimiter)
      const element = headers.reduce((object, header, index) => {
         object[header] = values[index]
         return object
      }, {})
      return element
   })

   return arr
}

inputForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()

   const input = file.files[0]
   const reader = new FileReader()

   reader.onload = function(e) {
      const text = e.target.result
      const data = csvToArray(text)
      
      table.appendChild(thead)
      table.appendChild(tbody)

      document.getElementById('data-table').appendChild(table)
      
      let hrow = document.createElement('tr')
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data[0]).length; i++) {
         let theader = document.createElement('th')

         theader.innerHTML = Object.keys(data[0])[i]
         hrow.appendChild(theader)
      }
      thead.appendChild(hrow)

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         let drow = document.createElement('tr')
         console.log(data[i])
         for (let j = 0; j < Object.values(data[i]).length; j++) {
            let tdata = document.createElement('td')

            tdata.innerHTML = Object.values(data[i])[j]

            drow.appendChild(tdata)
         }
         tbody.appendChild(drow)
      }
   }

   reader.readAsText(input)
})
```

This topic has large amount of tutorials in the net, but I haven't found the one I need.

I need to write a little site-navigator in xlsx file in a nutshell. This site has to support opportunity to **find all rows in file by a file** or **recieve all columns or rows** by the request from **input** field in `.html` file and output it on site in a table view.

The easiest way to import data from **.xlsx** file - `read-excel-file.min.js`. I've tried it, and the only thing I understood is that I recieve all **excel file data** in an **array** of rows.

So, if I want to recieve a row - I just write `data[index]`. 
To Recieve element - `data[index][index]`.

**In summary:** I try to understand, how to get **exact** data from .xlsx file by **filter(word) from input**

I tried to check other resources such as `Microsoft Office JS API` but haven't succeeded to understand it

If question is written not well or I haven't explained it in the right way - please correct me.

**
Example what I want to receive:

.xlsx:**

h1 | h2  | h3  | h4  | h5  | h6

---

d1 | d2  | d3  | d4  | d5  | d6

---

d1 | d22 | d33 | d44 | d55 | d66

---

d2 | d22 | d35 | d64 | d41 | d99

---

**Input: d1

Outputted table: **

---

d1 | d2  | d3  | d4  | d5  | d6

---

d1 | d22 | d33 | d44 | d55 | d66

---

My attempts:

**.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Excel Transform Site</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./excel-transfrom.css">
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <input type="file" class="file-choose">

         <label class="test-input-label">Test Input</label><br>
         <input type="text" class="test-input"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button">
      </form>

      <table class="tbl-excel></table>

      <script src="./excel-transform.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**.js:**

```js
let fileInput = document.querySelector(".file-choose")

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
   readXlsxFile(fileInput.files[0]).then((rows) => {
      console.log(rows)
   })
})
```

Comment: Are you asking: "How do I retrieve the row/cell with a specific value?"

If yes, then do you want to retrieve the first result, or do you want all results?

Comment: Yes! I need to receive all rows by a specific value. I will add an example what I want in the question

Comment: Are you using: https://sheetjs.com/

Comment: @JeffVdovjak No, never seen it yet

Comment: Where is read-excel-file.min.js from? It's hard to help you without knowing the tools you're using :)

Comment: @JeffVdovjak https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249957/discussion-between-lcashe-and-jeff-vdovjak).

Comment: Try using IndexOf on the array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: I recieve array of rows. Each row - array as well. It means I got 2 dimensional array and arr.indexOf doesn't work with 2D array. It will always return -1

Comment: You can use .map and .indexOf (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use .indexOf to retrieve a match in an array

Use .map to iterate through the outer array and find a single match.

Or use a loop to find multiple matches.

Since `rows` is an array of arrays returned from the Excel sheet, then use .map and inside your custom function, use .indexOf to search for the first occurrence of your search term.

This will find the first occurrence (with an exact match) and return the index of the row.

```
let search = 'd1';
let column_to_search = 0; // Looks in the first column in your spreadsheet
let match;
 
rows.map(
    function (element) {return element[column_to_search];}
).indexOf(search);
 
// output the array of the row
// (Don't forget to do logic if no match is found)
console.log(rows[match]);
```

This will create an array with all the rows that have an exact match in the column.

```
// Find all matches
let search = 'd1';
let column_to_search = 0; // Looks in the first column in your spreadsheet
let matches = Array();

// Go through the entire array of rows from the spreadsheet
for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    // Check to see if there is a match in the row
    if( rows[i].indexOf(search) > -1 ){
        // Add the row to the matches array
        matches.push(i);
    }
}

console.log(matches);
```

You could also use .reduce() to get all the matches

```
// Store matches
let matches = Array();  // Store the whole row of data, or
let matches_index = Array();    // Store just the index values

// Search Param
let search = 'd1';

// Column to search
let search_column = 0;

// Use .reduce() to integrate through rows
rows.reduce(
    (previousCall, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
      // Check to see if the column for this row contains a match
      if(search.localeCompare(currentValue[search_column]) == 0) {
          // Add to match (the full row)
          matches.push(currentValue);
          //Add just the index from rows
          matches_index.push(currentIndex);
      }
  },0
);
```